# A open subset of $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Given the definitions in [Open Subsets of open sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724540/open-subsets-of-open-sets)

I need to prove that $\{x \in \Bbb R : |x|>2\}$ is open in $(\Bbb R , d_E)$

This seems to be true, however I don't know how to prove it without referencing close sets.

Comment: Pick a point $x$ in your set, i.e. $|x| > 2$. Then show that there's some $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ which fully lies within your set. Hint: If $2 < x$, then $x - 2 > 0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to prove that $S:=\mathbb R \setminus [-2,2]$ is open.
Given $x\in S$ set $\delta := \min(|x-2|, |x+2|)$ the "Distance of $x$ to the complement".
Since $x\neq 2$ and $x\neq -2$, $\delta > 0$ so now
$$(x-\frac\delta2, x+\frac\delta2) = B_{\frac\delta2}(x) \subset S$$
Thus $x$ is an interior point. Since $x\in S$ was arbitrary, $S = S^\circ$ and thus $S$ is open.

Comment: Thanks, I assume the notation $S^\circ$ and $ int (S)$ are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of questions is useful theorem(you might take it as definition of continuous function)

> Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be continuous function. Than for any open $U\subset Y$ is $f^{-1}(U)$ open.

Now take continuous function $f(x) = |x|$. open interval $(2,\infty]$ is open therefore $f^{-1}( (2,\infty])$ is open.

Comment: This may be begging the question somewhat. After all, if they know that $(2, \infty)$ is open, then they probably also know that $(-\infty, -2)$ is open, and so since the union of open sets is open...

Comment: Ups silly me, I should read and think first :D I just saw question of type "is $\{ x : f(x)<2 \}$ open?". So I typed standard answer